# Concatenate sequence of frames from a NumPy array horizontally

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a NumPy array with size: `img_array.shape = (20, 10, 56, 56, 3)` which corresponds to 20 different sequences of 10 frames with size `(56, 56, 3)`. What to combine all 10 frames of each of these sequences into one bigger image. Therefore to output a new NumPy array with size `(20, 56, 560, 3)`, therefore, for each sequence to have an image of `(56, 560, 3)`.

How can I combine these frames? I tried to make use of NumPy reshape function but the result was not proper ones, I tried:

```
img_array = np.reshape(img_array, (20, 56, 560, 3))
```

While the image was created and I could store and see the result it was not correct rows were mixing together. How can I properly concatenate the images horizontally? Maybe by using hstacks, but I am not sure how exactly I can do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [`swapaxes`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.swapaxes.html) and [`reshape`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) to the specified shape:

```
a.swapaxes(2,1).reshape(20, 56, 560, 3)
```

Comment: Super awesome answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use `np.stack`, which can stack along your favorite dimension: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/numpy-stack-in-python/

Comment: `stack` treats the input as a list of arrays; in effect it iterates on the 1st, size 20 dimension.  It can move that dimension around, like `a.swpaaxes(n,0)`.  But the OP wants to move the 2nd, size 10 dimension.

Comment: @hpaulj stack takes an axis argument, so I have no idea what you mean.

Comment: How many different shapes can you produce with `stack` and a (2,3,4) shaped array? (3,2,4), (3,4,2)?